# react-router history.listener TypeScript definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

How can we define the *location* argument in useHistory hook of react-router-dom? I do not know what kind of type set because when I want to access to the key, it says that it does not exist (obvious, because it does not know what kind of object type is)

any idea?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

export const useBlockNavigation = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen(location: ??? => {
      // Type script error: Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Update<any>'
      const key = location.key;
      if (history.action === 'PUSH') {
        console.log('push')
      }
  
      if (history.action === 'POP') { 
        console.log('pop')
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is from another package `history`.

```
import { Location } from "history";

...

componentDidMount() {
  const { history } = this.props;

  const callBack = history.listen(location => this.onLocationUpdate(location));
}

...

onLocationUpdate = (location: Location<unknown>): void => {

}
```

Is how i have got it setup.